# Using Service Bus Queue InputObject Parameter on Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I have a Azure Service Bus Namespace which has hundreds of queues and I need to Set the **MaximumDeliveryCount** to 1 instead of a default value of 10. Doing it manually on portal will obviously take time. So I want to do it through PowerShell Script.

Not sure what should be the -InputObject Parameter. The Microsoft article [Set-AzServiceBusQueue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.servicebus/set-azservicebusqueue?view=azps-2.6.0) says that the InputObject Type is of PSQueueAttributes given here [PSQueueAttributes Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.commands.servicebus.models.psqueueattributes?view=azurerm-ps)

I tried entering 'MaxDeliveryCount' attribute but receiving this error:

```
Set-AzServiceBusQueue : Cannot bind parameter 'InputObject'. Cannot convert the "MaxDeliveryCount" value of type "System.String" to type 
"Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ServiceBus.Models.PSQueueAttributes".
At line:7 char:121
+ ...  $Servicebus_namespace -Name $_ -InputObject MaxDeliveryCount -WhatIf
+                                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-AzServiceBusQueue], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ServiceBus.Commands.Queue.SetAzureRmServiceBusQueue
```

Here is the code:

```
$Servicebus_queue = (Get-AzServiceBusQueue -ResourceGroupName $Resourcegroup_name -Namespace $Servicebus_namespace).Name

$Servicebus_queue


$Servicebus_queue.foreach{

    $Servicebus_queue = (Get-AzServiceBusQueue -ResourceGroupName $Resourcegroup_name -Namespace $Servicebus_namespace)

    $Servicebus_queue.MaxDeliveryCount = 1

    Set-AzServiceBusQueue -ResourceGroupName $Resourcegroup_name -Namespace $Servicebus_namespace -Name $_ -InputObject MaxDeliveryCount

}
```

I've researched everywhere but could not find any solution. Also the above links route to AzureRM module for Set-AzServiceBusQueue command.

Appreciate if anyone can help.

Comment: I think -InputObject needs to be a queue rather than the name of a property. Try “-InputObject $Servicebus_queue”.

Comment: @mclayton After making above changes it seems to work once. But If I run the script again I'm getting strange error: The property 'MaxDeliveryCount' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At line:1 char:5
+     $Servicebus_queue.MaxDeliveryCount = 1
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException
I think there is some kind of bug whichc is not recognizing this attribute the second time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment, you need to pass a queue object (i.e. a `PSQueueAttributes` instance) into `Set-AzServiceBusQueue`, but you've also got something slightly screwy going on with your variable assignments and your `foreach`.

The sample below should hopefully help straighten things out...

```bsh
# get a queue (or an array of queues). remove the ().Name as this just extracts
# their names and we really want the whole queue object. also, pluralise the
# variable name so it doesn't collide with our loop variables
$Servicebus_queues = Get-AzServiceBusQueue -ResourceGroupName $Resourcegroup_name -Namespace $Servicebus_namespace

$Servicebus_queues.foreach{

    # get a reference to the current ppieline variable
    # see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-6#_
    $Servicebus_queue = $_ 

    $Servicebus_queue.MaxDeliveryCount = 1

    # -InputObject needs to be a queue (i.e. a PSQueueAttributes instance)
    Set-AzServiceBusQueue -ResourceGroupName $Resourcegroup_name -Namespace $Servicebus_namespace -Name $_ -InputObject $Servicebus_queue

}
```

Comment: It seems to work now after setting $Servicebus_queue = $_ . Thanks for your help! Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, If you want to use the parameter `InputObject`, you can must provide PSQueueAttributes as its value. 
[image]

For example :

```
$Servicebus_queue = (Get-AzServiceBusQueue -ResourceGroupName $Resourcegroup_name -Namespace $Servicebus_namespace)

    $Servicebus_queue.MaxDeliveryCount = 1

    Set-AzServiceBusQueue -ResourceGroupName $Resourcegroup_name -Namespace $Servicebus_namespace -Name $_ -InputObject $Servicebus_queue
```

For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.servicebus/set-azservicebusqueue?view=azps-2.6.0).

**Update**

If you want to update Service Bus Queue with PowerShell, please refer to the following script

```
Connect-AzAccount

$ResourceGroupName=" "
$Namespace=" "

 $queues = Get-AzServiceBusQueue -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Namespace $Namespace

 foreach($queue in $queues){

   $queue.MaxDeliveryCount = 1
   Set-AzServiceBusQueue -ResourceGroup $ResourceGroupName -NamespaceName $Namespace -QueueName $queue.Name -QueueObj $queue

 }
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks but now I'm getting a different error for MaxDeliveryCount attribute as mentioned in the comments

Comment: I was getting this error: The property 'MaxDeliveryCount' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set. At line:1 char:5 + $Servicebus_queue.MaxDeliveryCount = 1 + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException   but I added $Servicebus_Queue = $_ command before setting MaxDeliveryCount as suggested by @mclayton and its working now.

Comment: @ARJ9 If the answer is useful for you, could you please accept the answer? If you do that, it can help more people.